# loader = importer.find_module(modname) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_module' on the second build of a jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, conda

I am new to Jenkins pipeline. And I have created a jenkins pipeline which has three stages wise.

- Code pull
- Creating Conda environment and install python dependencies
- Generate Binary Executable of my application using pyinstaller
  command
- Remove created conda environment

The binary gets created successfully on the very first build of the job. Below is the jenkins pipeline:

```
pipeline{
   agent any

    environment {
        PATH="/var/lib/jenkins/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
        CONDA_ENV="my-env"
    }

    stages {

        stage ("Code Pull"){
            steps{
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '$branch']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '9ccfe5fe-d057-48e0-b814-2aea006e26f7', url: '$gitrepo']]])

            }

        }
    stage('Create Conda Evironment') {
            steps {
                echo "Creating Conda Virtual Environment"

                sh  ''' conda create --yes -n ${CONDA_ENV} python==3.6.9
                        echo 'Environment Created Successfully'
                        source activate ${CONDA_ENV}
                        while read requirement; 
                        do 
                            conda install --yes $requirement || pip install $requirement; 
                        done < requirements.txt
                        pip install -r requirements-dev.txt
                        echo 'Dependencies Installed Successfully'
                    '''
            }
        }
    stage('Generate Binary Executable') {
            steps{
                echo "Generating Binary"
                sh  ''' source activate ${CONDA_ENV}
                        pyinstaller my_client.py --onefile --additional-hooks-dir=python/installer_utils
                    '''
            }
        }
    }
    post{
        always{
            echo "Remove Conda ENV"
            sh '''export PATH="/var/lib/jenkins/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
                  conda remove --yes -n ${CONDA_ENV} --all
                '''
        }

    }
}
```

But I get following error in the further builds of the pipeline.

> File "/var/lib/jenkins/miniconda3/...../site-packages/PyInstaller/building/utils.py", line 580, in _load_code
>           loader = importer.find_module(modname)
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_module'

Please suggest fix for this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by wiping the directory fetched from SCM in `post` stage.

```
post{
        always{
            echo "Remove Conda ENV"
            sh '''export PATH="/var/lib/jenkins/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
                  conda remove --yes -n ${CONDA_ENV} --all
                '''
           cleanup{deleteDir()}
        }
}
```